# how to build curve using xmldataprovider

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a code:

```
<Page x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Page.Resources>
    <XmlDataProvider x:Key="TestData" XPath="/Base">
        <x:XData>
            <Base>
                <Stage>
                    <Curve xstep="2">
                        <Point Value="10"/>
                        <Point Value="50"/>
                        <Point Value="20"/>
                        <Point Value="50"/>
                        <Point Value="30"/>
                    </Curve>
                </Stage>
            </Base>
        </x:XData>
    </XmlDataProvider>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="TestDataTemplate">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.LayoutTransform>
                <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1" ScaleY="-1" CenterX=".5" CenterY=".5" />
            </Grid.LayoutTransform>
            <Image>
                <Image.Source>
                    <DrawingImage>
                        <DrawingImage.Drawing>
                            <GeometryDrawing>
                                <GeometryDrawing.Pen>
                                    <Pen Brush="Red" Thickness="1"/>
                                </GeometryDrawing.Pen>
                                <GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                                    <PathGeometry>
                                        <PathFigure>
                                            <PolyLineSegment>
                                                <PolyLineSegment.Points>
                                                    <Point X="2" Y="{Binding ???}"/>
                                                </PolyLineSegment.Points>
                                            </PolyLineSegment>
                                        </PathFigure>
                                    </PathGeometry>
                                </GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                            </GeometryDrawing>
                        </DrawingImage.Drawing>
                    </DrawingImage>
                </Image.Source>
            </Image>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>

</Page.Resources>
<Grid Background="#DDD">
    <StackPanel>
        <ListBox
           Background="#999"
           BorderThickness="2"
           BorderBrush="White"
           Margin="10"
           ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource TestData}, XPath=Stage}"
           ItemTemplate="{StaticResource TestDataTemplate}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

I need to build a curve using the Point data of the Curve section of the XmlDocument.
I can't understand how to bind to the points of the PolylineSegment. Is there any way how to build it in only XAML without xaml-behind code. The problem I can't bind to the x and y coordinates of any point, because it's not dependency object. I need the only XAML code.

The x coordinate is calculated. It's started with 0 and increased for every new point by xstep. So the x coordinate of the first point is 0, the second is 2, the third is 4 and etc. The y-coordinate is taken as value of the Value element of the Point tag.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: is it a `Page` or a `Window`? `<Page.Resources>`... `</Window.Resources>` you may correct it if necessary. Also tell us what kind of data is represented by the XML?

Comment: It's a page. How to correct the post?

Comment: you just did it, now please explain the data in XML too.

Comment: The xml is represented in the XmlDataProvider. I need to get the Value and associate it with the point coordinate of the Polyline. Also I need to get x coordinate. It's increased for the new point as previous x coordinate + xstep. So the x coordinate of the first point is 0, the second is 2, the third is 4 and etc.

Comment: I was concerned about the explanation of the point value, usually a point has two values X & Y, but here is only one so what does it represent? appreciated if you can post an image of your expectation too.

Comment: The x coordinate is calculated. It's started with 0 and increased for every new point by xstep. So the x coordinate of the first point is 0, the second is 2, the third is 4 and etc.

Comment: thanks for your responce, I've just updated the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are stuck at `Y` property of a `Point` you may not be able to bind it as it is not a dependency property so that approach may not help you

I did try to achieve the same based on your comments.

```
<Grid Background="#DDD"
      xmlns:l="clr-namespace:CSharpWPF">
    <Grid.Resources>
        <XmlDataProvider x:Key="TestData"
                         XPath="/Base">
            <x:XData>
                <Base xmlns="">
                    <Stage>
                        <Curve xstep="2">
                            <Point Value="10" />
                            <Point Value="50" />
                            <Point Value="20" />
                            <Point Value="50" />
                            <Point Value="30" />
                        </Curve>
                    </Stage>
                </Base>
            </x:XData>
        </XmlDataProvider>
        <l:PointConverter x:Key="PointConverter" />
    </Grid.Resources>
    <StackPanel>
        <ListBox Background="#999"
                 BorderThickness="2"
                 BorderBrush="White"
                 Margin="10"
                 ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource TestData}, XPath=Stage/Curve}">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <Polyline Stroke="Red"
                                  StrokeThickness="1"
                                  Points="{Binding Converter={StaticResource PointConverter}}" />
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

you also need a converter as the points has to be calculated

```
namespace CSharpWPF
{
    class PointConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            XmlElement curve = value as XmlElement;
            PointCollection pc = new PointCollection();

            int x = 0;
            int increment = int.Parse(curve.Attributes["xstep"].Value);
            foreach (XmlElement item in curve.ChildNodes)
            {
                pc.Add(new Point(x, int.Parse(item.Attributes["Value"].Value)));
                x += increment;
            }
            return pc;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

result

[image: result]

see if this is what you expect. let me know if it differs

Comment: Thank you!, Is there any way to build the curve only in XAML without using a converter?

Comment: since values are calculated and not of Point type, pure xaml may not help you in this case.